# Double integral of the equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

How to implement this equation

[image]

in Matlab,

where: ***A*** and ***B*** are mxm matrices.

for example:

```
A = [3.45 32.54 78.2; 8.4 33.1 4.66; 68.2 9.336 33.87 ]

B = [6.45 36.54 28.24; 85.4 323.1 74.66; 98.2 93.336 38.55 ]
```

**my code:**

```
  f1 = @(A) (abs(A) ).^2;  
  f2 = @(B) (abs(B) ).^2; 
  Q = integral2( f1, 0, 1, 0, 1) * integral2(f2, 0, 1, 0, 1);
```

But when i run the code I got the error **"Too many input arguments."**.

What is the problem in the code?

Comment: An integral over all values of a matrix is a sum of its values

Comment: Are elements of  `A` and `B` a function of  `x` and `y`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri do you mean like this:
Q = sum(A) * sum(B)

Comment: @OmG yes they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarification of your question, let me change my post.

What you are after is numerical integration of a function that was already sampled on a fixed grid, and the function values are stored in matrices `A` and `B` that are two dimensional `M` by `M`. I suppose that you have the associated gridpoints as well, suppose they are denoted `xc` and `yc`. Then, if you have sufficiently fine sampling of a smooth function, the integral approaches:

```
xc = linspace(0,1,M);
yc = linspace(0,1,M);
Q = trapz(xc,trapz(yc, abs(A).^2)) * trapz(xc,trapz(yc, abs(B).^2 ));
```

To test that, I made a simple example that evaluates the surface of a circle, i.e. [image: formula]

so to do that with trapezoidal method with `N` samples for `r` and `M` samples for `phi`, we have,

```
r = 2;       % Pick a value for r
M = 100;     % Pick M samples for the angular coordinate from 0 to 2*pi
N = 101;     % Pick N samples for the radial coordinate from 0 to r
phic = linspace(0,2*pi,M);   % take M samples uniformly for example
rc = linspace(0,r,N);        % take N samples uniformly for example
integrand = repmat(rc,M,1);  % Make MxN matrix, phi along rows, r along columns
I = trapz(rc, trapz(phic, integrand));
```

So for the case `r=2`, it gives indeed `4*pi`.

Comment: I do not have the function that generate A and B matrices, I have only A and B as a MxM martrices. for example: 
A = [3.45 32.54 78.2; 8.4 33.1 4.66; 68.2 9.336 33.87 ]
B = [6.45 36.54 28.24; 85.4 323.1 74.66; 98.2 93.336 38.55 ]

Comment: In case you only know these values which I presume are at equally spaced coordinates, then I suggest to use the trapezoidal integration routine `trapz`. As an alternative, if A and B can be interpolated, you may be able to provide it still to the routine provided in the answer, by using `interp1` routine?

Comment: could you please check the following code, is it correct or not:
f1 = @(A) (abs(A) ).^2;  
f2 = @(B) (abs(B) ).^2;  
AA = trapz(A, trapz(A, f1, 2) );
BB = trapz(B, trapz(B, f2, 2) );
Q = AA .* BB;

Comment: I've changed the answer based on your new input

Comment: I have got this error when I run the code:
Error using trapz (line 57)
LENGTH(X) must equal the length of Y in dim 1.